# Doubt in proof of $\sum\limits_k\dot{q_k}\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial\dot{q_k}}=2T$

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differentiation

[image]

In the above picture, can someone explain how does the $1/2$ disappear when we consider the partial derivative of $T$ w.r.t $\dot{q_k}$

I'm thinking it's because of the symmetry of the function, i.e., we have, for symmetric $f(k,l)$, i.e., if $f(k,l)=f(l,k)$, then,

$$\sum\limits_k\sum\limits_l f(k,l)=2\sum\limits_l f(k,l)$$

But I'm not very sure because I can't seem to recall a proof for the above claim unless $k\lt l$ (which doesn't seem to be mentioned in the text). So, is there any different reason for the $1/2$ disappearing or am I in the right way?

Comment: Minor comment to the question (v1): It would be good if OP (or somebody else?) could try to make the question less vulnerable to link rot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the factor $1/2$ "disappears" is the following and it is, in fact, related to the symmetry of the matrix defining $T$ 
$$T= \sum_{h,k} a_{hk}\: \dot{q}^h\dot{q}^k\:,$$
but it works differently from your idea.

The center of your computation is
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial \dot{q}^r} \sum_{h,k} a_{hk}\:\dot{q}^h \dot{q}^k\:,\tag{1}$$ where $$a_{hk} = a_{kh}\:.\tag{2}$$
and $a_{hk}$ does not depend on any $\dot{q}^r$.

So you have 
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial \dot{q}^r} \sum_{h,k} a_{hk}\:\dot{q}^h \dot{q}^k= \sum_{h,k} a_{hk}\:\frac{\partial \dot{q}^h}{\partial \dot{q}^r} \dot{q}^k +  \sum_{h,k} a_{hk}\: \dot{q}^h\frac{\partial \dot{q}^k}{\partial \dot{q}^r} = \sum_{h,k} a_{hk}\:\delta_{hr} \dot{q}^k +  \sum_{h,k} a_{hk}\: \dot{q}^h\delta_{kr} =
\sum_{k} a_{rk}\: \dot{q}^k +  \sum_{h} a_{hr}\: \dot{q}^h
= \sum_{k} a_{rk}\: \dot{q}^k +  \sum_{k} a_{kr}\: \dot{q}^k
= \sum_{k} a_{rk}\: \dot{q}^k +  \sum_{k} a_{rk}\: \dot{q}^k
= 2\sum_{k} a_{rk}\: \dot{q}^k$$
In the last passage I used (2). Now the wanted result regarding kinetical energy immediately arises:
$$\sum_r\dot{q}^r\frac{\partial }{\partial \dot{q}^r} \sum_{h,k} a_{hk}\:\dot{q}^h \dot{q}^k= \sum_r\dot{q}^r 2\sum_{k} a_{rk}\: \dot{q}^k= 2 \sum_{r,k} a_{rk}\: \dot{q}^r\dot{q}^k = 2 \sum_{h,k} a_{hk}\: \dot{q}^h\dot{q}^k\:,$$
namely, if $$T= \sum_{h,k} a_{hk}\: \dot{q}^h\dot{q}^k\:,$$
we have
$$\sum_r\dot{q}^r\frac{\partial }{\partial \dot{q}^r} T = 2T\:.$$

Answer (score 0):

No, it is because of differentiation

Consider, for example

$$f=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^nq_iq_j=\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\sum_{i=0}^nq_i\bigg)^2$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial q_j}=\sum_{i=0}^nq_i$$

You can easily test it if you want by taking, say $n=2$ and evaluate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial q_1}$